# Discord.py looping messages up to infinity

Tags: discord, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client:
        return
    if message.channel.id == 885569828436447254:
        await message.channel.send(bgmi)
        await message.channel.send(news)
```

I am just trying to ping the role which is stored in variable `bgmi` for each message in a particular channel and it works!
But the glitch is that every time a message is received, the bot sends both the messages again and again until the bot is stopped. Please help me configure it and make it send the messages only a single time.

Comment: heyy, client is nothing just a class make that client to client.user , so it wont repeat same msg

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.guild is None or message.author == message.guild.me:
        return
    if message.channel.id == 885569828436447254:
        await message.channel.send(bgmi)
        await message.channel.send(news)
```

You should use [Guild.me](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild.me). In a guild, `message.author` is of Discord type `Member`, while client is just the python type used to manage the communication between discord. What you actually want is [Guild.me](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild.me)

This works only if the message is sent in a discord server, for private channels you'll need to do otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Replace `if message.author == client:` with `if message.author == client.user:`